# How to read datetime with timezone in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe from csv, and its first column is like

```
"2013-08-25T00:00:00-0400";
"2013-08-25T01:00:00-0400";
"2013-08-25T02:00:00-0400";
"2013-08-25T03:00:00-0400";
"2013-08-25T04:00:00-0400";
```

It's datetime with timezone ! I already used something like

```
df1 = DataFrame(pd.read_csv(PeriodC, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0))
```

but the result was

```
2013-09-02 04:00:00                                                                                    
2013-09-03 04:00:00                                                                                     
2013-09-04 04:00:00                                                                                     
2013-09-05 04:00:00                                                                                      
2013-09-06 04:00:00                                                                                     
2013-09-07 04:00:00                                                                                     
2013-09-08 04:00:00
```

Can anyone explain me how to seperate the datetime from timezone ?

Comment: Do you want to process just the datetime component or do you want to take into account the timezone?

Answer (score 29):

Pandas parser will take into account the timezone information if it's available, and give you a naive Timestamp (naive == no timezone info), but with the timezone offset taken into account.

To keep the timezone information in you DataFrame you should first localize the Timestamps as `UTC` and then convert them to their timezone (which in this case is `Etc/GMT+4`):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(PeriodC, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
>>> df.index[0]
>>> Timestamp('2013-08-25 04:00:00', tz=None)
>>> df.index = df.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Etc/GMT+4')
>>> df.index[0]
Timestamp('2013-08-25 00:00:00-0400', tz='Etc/GMT+4')
```

If you want to completely discard the timezone information, then just specify a `date_parser` that will split the string and pass only the datetime portion to the parser.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0]
                     date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.rpartition('-')[0]))
>>> df.index[0]
Timestamp('2013-08-25 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Comment: How comes a time with -4 is GMT+4 ? I thought the signs would be the same.

Comment: Is there no other option? I mean here you have to know in advance what timezone is in the date strings, which seems to defeat the point somewhat. I mean I guess I understand that there is no guarantee that all the dates in the input array will have the same offset, but kind of seems like they commonly would and that pandas could preserve this information. I guess stripping them out first and checking they are all the same manually is possible but just another place for me to make an error that the library could have protected me from.

Answer (score 1):

If you want also to convert all dates to utc (better for storing), you could do :

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0],
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, utc=True),
                 index_col=[0])
```

So you can select times with:

```
df.loc["2013-08-25"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pandas`, you can try

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't parse dates upon import of the csv but instead parse them in a second step with `pd.to_datetime`, you get the expected fixed UTC offset. Ex:

```
s = pd.Series(["2013-08-25T00:00:00-0400",
               "2013-08-25T01:00:00-0400",
               "2013-08-25T02:00:00-0400",
               "2013-08-25T03:00:00-0400",
               "2013-08-25T04:00:00-0400"])

pd.to_datetime(s)

0   2013-08-25 00:00:00-04:00
1   2013-08-25 01:00:00-04:00
2   2013-08-25 02:00:00-04:00
3   2013-08-25 03:00:00-04:00
4   2013-08-25 04:00:00-04:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)]
```

You can also parse to UTC directly:

```
pd.to_datetime(s, utc=True)

0   2013-08-25 04:00:00+00:00
1   2013-08-25 05:00:00+00:00
2   2013-08-25 06:00:00+00:00
3   2013-08-25 07:00:00+00:00
4   2013-08-25 08:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

(*`pd.__version__` 1.3.0*)