# How to specify time zone information when reading a csv with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, timezone

I have a csv file with a timestamp given in CAT (Central African Time). When I read it in as a pandas dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["timestamp"], dayfirst=True)
```

I get an error:

> C:\Users..\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser_parser.py:1218: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname CAT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
> category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)

which seems to indicate I need to pass a parameter tzinfos, but as far as I could see its not listed as an option for read_csv in the Pandas documentation. I tried both of:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["timestamp"], dayfirst=True, tzinfos={"CAT": "Etc/GMT+2"})
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["timestamp"], dayfirst=True, tzinfos= "Etc/GMT+2")
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfos'
```

Now at the moment its just a warning and it still reads it in as timezoneless data points to which I can just add the correct timezone info with: `df.timestamp.dt.tz_localize("Etc/GMT+2")`, however the fact that the warning says "In a future version, this will raise an exception" makes me think my code will break in the future so I would prefer to fix it now.

I tried googling for a solution but all the results seem to do with general datetime conversions, not reading in a csv (I couldn't figure out how the results translate).

[image: Example of the data]

Comment: could you please add the sample data as text instead of image? copy&paste is better than OCR ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911241/how-to-read-datetime-with-timezone-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tzinfos` is an argument for [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html). It cannot be supplied to [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (or [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)) directly, afaik.

Instead, you can read the csv without parsing the dates, import the parser, and apply it with the kwarg, Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser, tz

s = pd.Series(["01-Apr-17 12:00:00 AM CAT"])

# use tzfile Africa/Maputo for CAT:
s = s.apply(parser.parse, tzinfos={"CAT": tz.gettz("Africa/Maputo")})

s
0   2017-04-01 00:00:00+02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Maputo')]
```

Answer (score 0):

## A one liner importing only pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv', date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_localize('US/Eastern'))
```