# Converting from local time to UTC time in Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How would I efficiently convert local times in a dataframe to UTC times? There are 3 columns with information: the date (string), the timezone code (string), and the hour of the day (integer).

| date | timezone | hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/31/2010 0:00:00 | EST | 1 |
| 6/14/2010 0:00:00 | PST | 3 |
| 6/14/2010 0:00:00 | PST | 4 |
| 5/30/2010 0:00:00 | EDT | 23 |
| 5/30/2010 0:00:00 | EDT | 24 |

After the data is converted I will be aggregating it to monthly data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify time zone information when reading a csv with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941786/how-to-specify-time-zone-information-when-reading-a-csv-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Gday.

Working with dates is described reasonably well in this answer here: [converting utc to est time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284274/converting-utc-to-est-time-in-python)

In that case they have the timezone offsets as numbers e.g +11:00. You have the US short code. So you could convert that column to the numerical equivalent first and then use that function.

Personally I find the notation "Australia/Melbourne" way easier to deal with - especially because it thinks about daylight savings etc for you. Timezones are a nightmare. Thats described here: [Python: datetime tzinfo time zone names documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692906/python-datetime-tzinfo-time-zone-names-documentation)

In terms of the hour column, you can just use a string function to join those two values together to form a date and time string.

So I'd suggest you convert that timezone column to that format (I.e EST as America/New York), etc, then feed all three columns into a datetime convert line per the first answer

Comment: +1 for suggesting [IANA names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Abbreviated tz names is one thing that can make tz handling painful. They're ambiguous. Not something you want to teach a computer.